# Spring Cloud DataFlow Composed Task doesn't start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm trying to run SCDF Composed Task.
Any composed tasks that I create does the same thing: executes SQL script:

> Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql]`

And on that point execution pauses. In `Executions` tab of SCDF Dashboard at `Start time` and `End time` I see `N/A`.

I'm using Spring Cloud DataFlow 1.2.3.RELEASE and
Composed Task Runner 1.0.0.RELEASE.

Here's the output from logs:

> 2017-08-18 18:20:09.455  INFO 828 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
>   2017-08-18 18:20:10.528  WARN 828 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/composedtaskrunner-task/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>   2017-08-18 18:20:10.530  INFO 828 --- [           main] .t.a.c.ComposedtaskrunnerTaskApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>   2017-08-18 18:20:10.567  INFO 828 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@61a52fbd: startup date [Fri Aug 18 18:20:10 EEST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3b95a09c
>   2017-08-18 18:20:10.903  INFO 828 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/configuration/SimpleTaskConfiguration.class]]
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.150  INFO 828 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=03034f55-14f0-32fd-9b4a-577a14282248
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.161  WARN 828 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.167  WARN 828 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.218  INFO 828 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$591cf5d8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.224  INFO 828 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d02f2db] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.250  INFO 828 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2729e67] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.258  INFO 828 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac8a86a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2017-08-18 18:20:11.655  INFO 828 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql]`

And in server logs I see a lot of different characters changing over time, for ex.:
`"[0x0][0x0][0x8][0x8][0x0][0xfa]CaJ[\r]3[0x99][0xd4]}[0x3][0x0][0x0][0x87][0x6][0x0][0x0]3[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xa4][0x81] c[\n]"`

Sorry for formatting, cannot properly format output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was in h2 versions incompatibility in Composed Task Runner and SCDF.